# ActiveReports6 - display column headers on all report pages

Tags: report

I have a report that has 10 pages redered in ActiveReports6.
It seems impossible to display colmn headers on all pages.
They are displayed on first page, but starting with the second page, row headers are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
You need to set the RepeatStyle of a group header to

```
DataDynamics.ActiveReports.RepeatStyle.OnPage
```